# Bound for the bias of ergodic averages for non-stationary Markov chains

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, markov-process

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space
- $X$ be a $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued time-homogeneous $\mathcal F$-Markov chain on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with transition kernel $\kappa$, initial distribution $\nu$ and stationary distribution $\mu$
- $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu)$ and $$A_{b,\:n}f:=\frac1n\sum_{i=b}^{b+n-1}f(X_i)$$ for some $b\in\mathbb N_0$ and $n\in\mathbb N$

I'm interested in the bias of the estimator $A_{b,\:n}f$ of $$\mu f:=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu.$$ Actually, if $f$ is bounded, then it's not hard to show that $$\left|\operatorname E\left[A_{b,\:n}f\right]-\mu f\right|\le\left|\nu\kappa^b-\mu\right|\sup_{x\in E}\left|f_0(x)\right|\tag1,$$ where $\left|\nu\kappa^b-\mu\right|$ is the total variation distance of $\nu\kappa^b$ and $\mu$ and $f_0:=f-\mu f$.

> Boundedness in $(1)$ is already needed in order to ensure that $\operatorname E\left[A_{b,\:n}f\right]$ is well-defined. We know that $$\operatorname P\circ X_n=\underbrace{\left(\operatorname P\circ X_0\right)}_{=\:\nu}\kappa^n.\tag2$$ Is it somehow possible to drop the boundedness assumption in $(1)$, i.e. is there a similar statement for a general $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu)$?

Clearly, the question becomes trivial whenver $\mu$ is invariant with respect to $\kappa$ (since then $\operatorname P\circ X_n=\mu=\nu$).

---

*Remark*: In my application, $X$ is generated by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm and I'm trying to figure out how "good" the approximation $A_{b,\:n}f$ of $\mu f$ is.